# MongoDB will not push to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function that's sole purpose is to push an object to an array in mongodb. This does not push to the array, how ever, and I have no idea why.
The code is:

```
itemfunctions.addItem = function(itemname, username) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {
        if (user.inventory.length < 47) {
            return false;
        };
        var item = itemfunctions.itemInvTemplate; //{metadata: [], name: "", durability: null}
        var iteminfo = itemfunctions.getItem(itemname);
        item.name = itemname;
        item.durabilty = iteminfo.durability;
        User.findOneAndUpdate({username: username }, { $push: { inventory: item } },
            function (error, success) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                return true;
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: How does your User schema look like?

Comment: I figured it out, I did < instead of > :p

Comment: Oh, that’s goos.